# Add apostrophe to Wordpress URL?

Tags: wordpress, url, apostrophe

I am trying to rebuild some old URLs on my website.
In the past I had a page like this:

`site.com/let's-dance/`

However when I try to rebuild it in wordpress I get "lets" instead of "let's"

`site.com/lets-dance/`

How can I add an apostrophe to the wordpress URL?

I don't even know what to try.

Comment: Use a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress will strip off special characters, since they can cause issues when writing to the database. It's best practice to avoid using special (reserved) characters in URLs, as they can and will break when passing them around. Case in point, see your own post and the cutting off of the URL after the '.

Comment: not true, the very reason why URL Encoding exists is to be able to use symbols in urls. For the record, url-encoded apostrophe is `%27` (not that it NEEDS to be encoded, it has no particular meaning in http)